# how can i call data from a model class which in list model flutter

Tags: flutter, serialization

I am trying to get data from my model but I am not getting the data in text widget.After receiving data from JSON I am using model to save data I am able to print data after API call in function but not when I tried to get data from model inside widget.I am using `provider` but receiving null value from model I am not getting exactly how to achieve this task following is my JSON object

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"success": true,
"messages": [],
"data": [
 
    {
        "id": 36,
        "title": "Muhurtam",
        "filename": "Muhurtam.jpg",
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "directcalling": 1,
        "parentid": null,
        "subcat": [
            {
                "id": 50,
                "title": "abc",
                "filename": "abc.png",
                "mimetype": "image/png",
                "directcalling": 0,
                "parentid": 36,
                "subcat": []
            }
        ]
```

I had created model class for the above json below is my model

**Model**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Categories with ChangeNotifier {
  Categories({
    this.statusCode,
    this.success,
    this.messages,
    this.data,
  });
  late final int? statusCode;
  late final bool? success;
  late final List<dynamic>? messages;
  late final List<Data>? data;

  Categories.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    statusCode = json['statusCode'];
    success = json['success'];
    messages = List.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic>(json['messages']);
    data = List.from(json['data']).map((e) => Data.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['statusCode'] = statusCode;
    _data['success'] = success;
    _data['messages'] = messages;
    _data['data'] = data!.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }

  List get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [...data!];
  }
}

class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
  Data({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.filename,
    this.mimetype,
    this.directcalling,
    this.parentid,
    this.subcat,
  });
  late final int? id;
  late final String? title;
  late final String? filename;
  late final String? mimetype;
  late final int? directcalling;
  late final Null parentid;
  late final List<Subcat>? subcat;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    filename = json['filename'];
    mimetype = json['mimetype'];
    directcalling = json['directcalling'];
    parentid = null;
    subcat = List.from(json['subcat']).map((e) => Subcat.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    // _data['id'] = id;
    _data['title'] = title;
    _data['filename'] = filename;
    // _data['mimetype'] = mimetype;
    _data['directcalling'] = directcalling;
    // _data['parentid'] = parentid;
    // _data['subcat'] = subcat.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Subcat {
  Subcat({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.filename,
    required this.mimetype,
    required this.directcalling,
    required this.parentid,
    required this.subcat,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String title;
  late final String filename;
  late final String mimetype;
  late final int directcalling;
  late final int parentid;
  late final List<dynamic> subcat;

  Subcat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    filename = json['filename'];
    mimetype = json['mimetype'];
    directcalling = json['directcalling'];
    parentid = json['parentid'];
    subcat = List.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic>(json['subcat']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    //_data['id'] = id;
    _data['title'] = title;
    _data['filename'] = filename;
    //_data['mimetype'] = mimetype;
    _data['directcalling'] = directcalling;
    //_data['parentid'] = parentid;
    //_data['subcat'] = subcat;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

following is my widget where I want to check data inside my model.i am not getting exactly how to call data which is inside model

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var image = Provider.of<FlutterFunctions>(context, listen: false);
   var cat = Provider.of<Category>(context, listen: false).categories;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const AppDrawer(),
      body:  Text("${cat?.data == null ? "there is no data" : cat!.statusCode}")
```

**Api Conversion**

```
     class Category with ChangeNotifier {
  Categories? categories;
  Future<void> getCatogories(BuildContext cont) async {
    final url = PurohitApi().baseUrl + PurohitApi().getcategory;

    try {
      final client = RetryClient(
        http.Client(),
        retries: 4,
        when: (response) {
          return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
        },
        onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) async {
          //print('retry started $token');

          if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
            var accessToken = await Provider.of<Auth>(cont, listen: false)
                .restoreAccessToken();
            // Only this block can run (once) until done

            req.headers['Authorization'] = accessToken;
          }
        },
      );
      var response = await client.get(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      );
      Map<String, dynamic> categoryTypes = json.decode(response.body);

      categories = Categories.fromJson(categoryTypes);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use one of these sites to parse your `json` to `Dart` code: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ or https://app.quicktype.io . Or you can use `Visual Studio Code` extension called `Json to Dart Model` for the same purpose.

Comment: yeah I had already converted it but I want to use converted data inside widgets

Comment: If you've done the model conversion correctly, then I suspect the part where you call it. Can you update your question with the code where you call the conversion from json (after the api response).

Comment: update with conversion I am Abel to print data from function where I am calling api but I an not receiving data inside widgets

Comment: You are not assigning your converted categories anywhere. Should be something like: `yourCategoriesInProvider = Categories.fromJson(categoryTypes);`

Comment: I had updated the question I had tried as you said  but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Provider` the wrong way. Your models such as `Categories`,`Data` etc. should not extend ChangeNotifier. You have to make `Provider` class which uses `ChangeNotifier` which will have your model data and provide it somewhere to use it with `Provider.of<ProviderName>(context, listen: false)`. Something like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => CategoriesProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Sample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoriesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Categories? categories;

  Future<void> getCatogories() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> categoryTypes = {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "success": true,
      "messages": [],
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 36,
          "title": "Muhurtam",
          "filename": "Muhurtam.jpg",
          "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
          "directcalling": 1,
          "parentid": null,
          "subcat": [
            {
              "id": 50,
              "title": "abc",
              "filename": "abc.png",
              "mimetype": "image/png",
              "directcalling": 0,
              "parentid": 36,
              "subcat": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    categories = Categories.fromJson(categoryTypes);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Sample> createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<CategoriesProvider>(context, listen: false).getCatogories();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var cat = Provider.of<CategoriesProvider>(context, listen: false).categories;
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      body: Text("${cat?.data == null ? "there is no data" : cat!.statusCode}"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had updated the question as you said I had used my model in a variable then I assign my conversion to the model and I had tried to called data by using following code but I had not received any data `cat.categories!.statusCode`

Comment: Follow my answer and create your `Provider` like I did with `CategoriesProvider`. Provide it to your widget tree with `ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => CategoriesProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Sample(),
      ),`, and use it as I did with `var cat = Provider.of<CategoriesProvider>(context, listen: false).categories;` to get your categories into a variable and use it further in the widget tree.

Comment: I had edited my question and code had tried what you had said by creating provider as you said in Category class you can check my Api conversion code in the question and I am calling categories from api conversion in my widget but it is not working

Comment: Any errors? I don't know where is your problem now, but my answer works perfectly, you can test it and see it, then adjust it to your needs.

Comment: hmm there is know problem in your code but I am not getting why it is not working

Comment: it worked thank you I had just remove change notifier from model

Comment: Yes, as I said in the answer. Glad it worked, happy coding 